# how to fix a java.lang.NumberFormatException error where the desire input is string?

Tags: java, swing

i'm using Jframe as my front-end for an inventory system i have developed. I'm getting a "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:"6seater"" but the variable is declared as a string so i'm a bit confused as to why this error is coming up

```
private String Eng_num, Chasis_num, make, model, year_of_car,capacity,description;
private Integer status,Sup_id;

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    Insert I = new Insert();

    try
    {
        Chasis_num = textField_1.getText();
        Eng_num = textField_9.getText();
        year_of_car = textField_10.getText();  
        model = textField_11.getText(); 
        make = textField_12.getText();
        capacity = textField_14.getText();//error is at this line
        description = textField_16.getText();
        Sup_id = Integer.parseInt(""+textField_13.getText().toString());
        status = Integer.parseInt(""+textField_15.getText().toString());

        I.insertVehicle(Eng_num, Chasis_num, make, model, year_of_car, capacity, Sup_id, status, description);
    }
```

I even try to put .toString and still getting the same error

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Without the stack trace, and full code, it's almost impossible to give you an accurate answer. Please follow MadProgrammer's link and format your code correctly after that.

Comment: Also give your textFields more appropiate names, probably `textField_14`'s text isn't `6seater` but `6seater` is `textField_13`'s text, however these are all a guess of mine, so, please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks! :) We just want you to help us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
capacity = textField_14.getText();
```

I don't think this is the cause of your exception.

`java.lang.NumberFormatException`Only occur when you try to parse `String` into any kind of `Number`.

So, i'm guessing, this exception was thrown somewhere you try to convert `6seater` to `Int` or some other number format.

Comment: Provide the complete code and we'll try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm getting a "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:"6seater"" but the variable is declared as a string so i'm a bit confused as to why this error is coming up.

The error is happening because you have tried to parse the characters `6seater` as an integer.  It isn't an integer.  An integer consists of the characters `0` through `9`, possibly with a `-` character at the front.  Any other character, and the value will be rejected ...

(The problem is nothing to do with the type that `getText()` returns.  The problem is the value that you are giving to the `parseInt` method.  It is not clear *where* the `parseInt` call is.  A stacktrace would answer that ... but you didn't provide one.)

---

Also, you say:

```
    capacity = textField_14.getText();//error is at this line
```

Actually, it isn't.  That line cannot possibly throw a `NumberFormatException`.  In reality, the error could be happening at one of these lines:

```
    Sup_id = Integer.parseInt(""+textField_13.getText().toString());
    status = Integer.parseInt(""+textField_15.getText().toString());
```

or it could be happening *within* the the `insertVehicle` method that you are calling here:

```
    I.insertVehicle(Eng_num, Chasis_num, make, model, 
                    year_of_car, capacity, Sup_id, status, description);
```

---

I should also point out that you have made some egregious Java style errors in your code:

- Java class, method or variable names should never contain `_` as a separator.  Use "camel case".
- A Java variable name should never start with an uppercase letter.

<sup>(If you instructor doesn't deduct "style" marks for this, he/she should.  If your code reviewers don't pick this up, they are not doing their job properly.  If this code was intended to be delivered to a paying customer, they would have reason to complain about the code quality ...)</sup>

Comment: Google for "Java style guide" and pick one.  The identifier style rules are pretty much universal for Java.